# What is the proper way of designing this viewModel with blocks in MVVM design?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, viewmodel, objective-c-blocks

I am developing a register function for my app using MVVM design.

I've created a sharedInstance class and implemented the register method using block like this:

```
- (void)registerUserWithName:(NSString *)name
                   phone:(NSString *)phone
                password:(NSString *)password
              completion:(CompletionBlock)aCallback
{
    UserModel *user = [[UserModel alloc] init];
      user.name = name;
      user.phone = phone;
      user.password = password;

[[self.client registerUser:user].task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        aCallback(NO, task.error);
        return nil;
    }
    aCallback(YES, nil);
    return nil;
}];
}
```

In MVC design, I would just do this to call this method:

```
 GlobalFunctions *function = [GlobalFunctions sharedInstance];
[function registerUserWithName:name phone:number password:password completion:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSError *error) {
    if(isSuccess){
        ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}];
```

I tried to apply this code to the MVVM design. In my viewModel, I have:

```
-(BOOL)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password{
RBCFunctions *function = [RBCFunctions sharedInstance];
[function registerUserWithName:name phone:number password:password completion:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSError *error) {
    return isSuccess;
}];
}
```

However, this doesn't work because I get a compiler error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending BOOL
```

How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're trying to return a boolean value from a block with return type `void`. Look at my comments in this code,

```
-(BOOL)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password{ 
// Begin method that returns BOOL
    RBCFunctions *function = [RBCFunctions sharedInstance];
// Call function that takes a completion handler that returns VOID!
    [function registerUserWithName:name phone:number password:password completion:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSError *error) {
        // Returning BOOL in block that should return VOID!
        return isSuccess;
    }];
    // NO RETURN VALUE!
}
```

If you are dealing with blocks (AKA asynchronous programming) and you want to pass values around, you need to create more blocks so your code would look like this:

```
-(void)registerUserWithUser:(NSString*)name withPhone: (NSString*)number withPassword: (NSString*)password handler:(void(^)(BOOL success))handler{
RBCFunctions *function = [RBCFunctions sharedInstance];
[function registerUserWithName:name phone:number password:password completion:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSError *error) {
    !handler ?: handler(isSuccess);
    // The above line is equivalent to:
    /*
    if (handler) {
        handler(isSuccess);
    }
    */
}];
}
```

That way you would call it like this:

```
[self registerUserWithUser:@"Badass" withPhone:@"01234567891" withPassword:@"password" handler:^(BOOL OK) {
    if (OK) {
        // Boss!
    } else {
        // Ahh NO!
    }
}];
```

A few things to be aware of:

- 1) If your block variable is nil and you call it (i.e. `myBlock(args)`) then your app will crash. You need to test for existence before calling blocks; the easiest way to do this is with the ternary operator: `!myBlock ?: myBlock(args);`
- 2) Are you sure your `RCBFunctions` class needs to be a singleton? It is easy once you know about singletons to use them all over the place when they're not needed (I've done it myself before). Might it not be easier to add the registration code to the `UserModel` class? I.e. :

  `[myUser registerWithCallback:^(BOOL success) {
      // Blah blah
  }];`